# Selecting rows with column value in other column list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the following format:

```
col1  col2  ...      col4
   A     2        [2-3-4]
   B     3        [2-6]
   A     3        [2-3-4]
   C     2        [2-3-4]
   D     2        [2-3-4]
```

I would like to select only the rows where the value in col2 is in the list of col4.

I tried to use:

```
df[(df["col2"].isin(df["col4"].str.split("-"))]
```

but I get an empty data frame...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension here for this usecase:

```
df[[str(a) in b for a,b in zip(df['col2'],df['col4'])]]
```

---

```
  col1  col2     col4
0    A     2  [2-3-4]
2    A     3  [2-3-4]
3    C     2  [2-3-4]
4    D     2  [2-3-4]
```

---

Or using regex search which will not match 2 with 22 `#thanks @Nk03`

```
import re
df[[bool(re.search(fr'\b{a}\b',b)) for a,b in zip(df['col2'],df['col4'])]]
```

Comment: Just one issue that I can see here. Let's say if df['col2'] contains 2 and df['col4'] contains [22-3-1]. Then also it'll mark it as True.   Am I missing anything here? @anky

Comment: @Nk03 Thanks, good point, updated my answer with word boundaries to match full strings

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
df['col4'] = df.col4.astype(str).str.replace('-',',')
df['col2'] = df.col2.astype(str)
df= df[df.apply(lambda x: x.col2 in x.col4, axis=1)]
```

**Output**

```
    col1    col2    col4
0   A       2   [2,3,4]
2   A       3   [2,3,4]
3   C       2   [2,3,4]
4   D       2   [2,3,4]
```

Comment: It will work without converting the string into list of elements. No need to convert you are using `in`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import ast
df.col4 = df.col4.str.replace('-',',').apply(ast.literal_eval)
new_df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['col2'] in x['col4'], axis =1)]
```